# Preference List only shows first element

Tags: android, android-listview, android-preferences

I am developing a `PreferenceActivity` with custom `Preference` views. My problem is that I created a view with a `ListView` and it only shows the first element. I post my code and an image:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/sc20120307161530.png/

http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/7207/sc20120307161530.png' border='0'/>

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="player_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings_player_config" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="@string/settings_player_default_name"
            android:dialogMessage="@string/settings_player_summary"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/settings_playersname"
            android:key="player_name"
            android:summary="@string/settings_player_summary"
            android:title="@string/settings_playersname" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="volume"
        android:title="@string/settings_volume" >
        <com.battleship.preferences.SeekBarPreferences
            android:defaultValue="50"
            android:key="volume"
            android:title="@string/settings_volume" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="shine"
        android:title="@string/settings_shine" >
        <com.battleship.preferences.SeekBarPreferences
            android:defaultValue="50"
            android:key="shine"
            android:title="@string/settings_shine" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="themeTitle"
        android:title="@string/settings_group_themes" >
        <com.battleship.preferences.ListPreferences android:key="theme" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="fontsTitle"
        android:title="@string/settings_group_font_size" >
        <com.battleship.preferences.ListPreferences android:key="font" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The Custom ListPreference:

```
package com.battleship.preferences;

import com.battleship.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListPreferences extends Preference implements
        OnCheckedChangeListener {

    public ListPreferences(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ListPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ListPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick() {

        super.onClick();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "HOLA!", 3);
        t.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {



        String[] contentString = new String[3];
        if (getKey().equals("theme")) {
            contentString = new String[] {
                    (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_theme_default)),
                    (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_theme_black)),
                    (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_theme_white)) };
        } else {
            contentString = new String[] {
                    (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_font_big)),
                    (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_font_medium)),
                    (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_font_little)) };
        }

        ListView listView = new ListView(getContext());
        ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                android.R.id.text1, contentString);
        listView.setAdapter(array);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


        return listView;
    }

    private void updatePreference(int intRadio) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor();
        editor.putInt(getKey(), intRadio);
        editor.commit();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you hate it when everyone tries to tell you that you shouldn't do it that way instead of just answering your question? Being able to dynamically generate content is crucial to app flexibility, I totally know what you're after.

This will work assuming all the ListView entries will be roughly the same height (non-pertinent parts omitted). The order is important, try to keep it as I've indicated:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener;

public class ListPreferences extends Preference implements
    OnCheckedChangeListener, OnHierarchyChangeListener {

private ListView listView;
private View thisView;
private int listHeight = 0;

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    this.setLayoutResource(R.layout.listview_preference_layout);
    thisView = super.onCreateView(parent);
    listView = (ListView) thisView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(this);
    String[] contentString = new String[3];
    if (getKey().equals("theme")) {
        contentString = new String[] {
        (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_theme_default)),
        (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_theme_black)),
        (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_theme_white)) };
    } else {
        contentString = new String[] {
        (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_font_big)),
        (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_font_medium)),
        (getContext().getString(R.string.settings_font_little)) };
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
        android.R.id.text1, contentString);
    listView.setAdapter(array);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    return thisView;
}

public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
    int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
    if(childHeight > 0)
    {
        listHeight = listView.getAdapter().getCount() * childHeight;
        thisView.setMinimumHeight(listHeight);
        Log.i(TAG,"onChildViewAdded, done: "+listHeight+" "+childHeight);
    }
}

public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
}


}
```

You'll also need res/layout/listview_preference_layout.xml with the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal|fill"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:clipChildren="true" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal|fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</LinearLayout
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this!!

Comment: What part isn't what you expected? I'd be glad to help troubleshoot any other issues if needed.

Comment: Thanks, are you being so helpful. Ok, I am developing an accessible app, and I need to build a GUI adapted to the Talkback. When the focus get the listView, it get all the listView, and don't go into the elements...any idea?   Other issue. When I press in the elements of the listView, appears a little scroll, like this listViews have an individual scroll apart from the global scroll...how can I build not scrollables listViews? Thanks Thanks Thanks

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you're saying that the individual  dynamic listviews aren't being sized to match the combined height of the preferences in them? Can you post your new source code for ListPreferences (just add it as an answer, we can edit back and forth as needed and delete when done)

Comment: Here it is!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904890/focus-not-working-as-expected-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to add a ListView as an item of another ListView. ListView is used in the layout of the PreferenceActivity. Therefore it doesn't work.

I don't understand why you don't want to go with the standard solution, ListPreference. It is made exactly for the purpose of presenting a user with a list of radio buttons.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to use the ListPreference solution because I am developing an accessible app, and the Talkback is not working properly in the Dialogs, so I need another way to show this RadioButtons. I tried with a RadioGroup but the navigation is not correct. The focus get the RadioGroup instead the RadioButtons. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @jmunoz That's OK if you don't want to use a dialog, you can just use another screen. And on that screen place all the items you wanted to show as a radio group.

Comment: Yes, I know I can use other screen but, what I want to do is place all the options in a Preference Screen, to make the settings of the app with a more simple navigation

Comment: @jmunoz I can't find documentation from SDK, but it seems you can't have nested `ListView`. Consider using [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)? Btw, I don't understand this phrase: "_the Talkback is not working properly in the Dialogs_". If you want a custom dialog, just use `<Preference>`, and handle its click listener.

Comment: The Talkback (the screen reader used by Android), don't work for Dialogs navigation. I tried to use the ExpandableListView, but when I build the inside objects (I suppose that I need to use RadioGroup), can't get view from the Child. I think that I'm making it wrong. It semms that I can`t use the ListView. Thanks!

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with adding a ListView to another ListView. The _problems_ are that 1.) onCreateView in this context is expected to return a view laid out by the parent ViewGroup and 2.) The ListView he is creating has no layout parameters.

Comment: @JustinBuser The answer "you can't do that" is an answer, too. Of course, it is nice to know that there is actually a way, so you have +1 personally from me.

Comment: @Malcolm - Thanks, much appreciated.  I hear what you're saying but it seems like every time I start looking for an answer to something there are 10 times more posts from people who don't really know what they are talking about than actual answers. I always approach every situation from the standpoint of "it can't be done" just means that no one else has done it yet. For example my Erotic LiveWallpapers app in the market renders video via OpenGL as a Live Wallpaper which is something that I found tons of forum posts/topics about, all of which claiming it wasn't possible. (1,000,000+ downloads)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you create a custom layout for Preferences. You can then create and style your Preferences to how you like. And using the `SharedPreferences` from `PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreferences()` will allow you to save any changes as if you were using the normal Preferences solution.

As Malcolm suggested, you should probably adhere to the common practices, and not try to do anything to complex here.

Another suggestion, is dont use a ListView. Instead if you want all of your Views to be displayed, manually add these to a LinearLayout, which you then place inside your Preference View.

Comment: How is this in any way an answer to his question? Do you not see the  30 or so lines of "custom layout for Preferences" that makes up 50% of his post? Do you also not see his code that uses the SharedPreferences class to save preferences? Do you not realize that the core component of a PreferenceActivity is a ListView, why wouldn't he want to make use of it? He doesn't want you to tell him not to build complex solutions, he want's to learn how to make the complex solutions work properly so he can build more than just the basic API samples that you're referring to.